# Hiding label when datepicker hides

Tags: javascript, html, grails, datepicker, filtering

I have a filter option on a application that that allows you to pick a day "From" and "To" To help filter out events in my database. Since this isn't the only filter I have, theres a drop-down menu to pick which filter you want. When you are at the datepicker drop-down menu. The options to pick the dates appear in two text field boxes. When the project was first implemented the date picker fields did not have labels. I added labels to the boxes "From" and "To" respectively.

label for="startDate">From:label

with the "< label" "/label>" tags appropriately

This is the simple code I added. Which appended itself to the datepicker element "startDate"

Now since this option is hidden/shown according to if the user is wanting to use this filter. The option comes and goes but now the labels stay on the page. I figured that in the code the handles the date picker, and that I appended the label to this element. That the label will be shown/hidden with it.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing or maybe just not understanding? Im new to javascript and html.

Any opinions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your javascript code that shows/hide elements and also your html?

Answer (score -1):

If using Mootools DatePicker, try adding to onSelect function :
use a selector to get the specific label and then the .hide().

Comment: 1) The OP didn't ask about Mootools. 2) You should provide code examples.